# MvxBundle is empty during Navigation to the new ViewModel

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm migrated app from MvvmCross 5.x to MvvmCross 6.1.2 and now I have problem with ntransferring bundle during navigation.

`IMvxNavigationService` is initialised and passed to VM thru constructor.

Now I try to pass a MvxBundle to the `MainViewModel` with next call

```
NavigationService.Navigate<MainViewModel>(new MvxBundle(new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    {"key1","value1" },
    {"key2","value2" },
}));
```

In the `MainViewModel` I override `InitFromBundle`

```
protected override void InitFromBundle(IMvxBundle parameters)
{
    base.InitFromBundle(parameters);
}
```

But `parameters` is empty.  `parameters.Data` doesn't contains my `Dictionary`.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For navigation use

```
NavigationService.Navigate<ViewModel, Parameter type>(parapeter)
```

Parameter can be any reference type. For example

```
await NavigationService.Navigate<MainViewModel, Dictionary<String, String>>(new Dictionary<String, String> {{"", ""}});
```

ViewModel on which you are navigating must inherit `MvxViewModel<MyObject>` and override `Prepare` method

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public override void Prepare(Dictionary<String, String> parameter)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I already implement this approach. I saw it in MvvmCross samples. Do you know why bundles not working?